# Как вывести два столбца через функцию с курсором (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

У меня есть функция, которая принимает 3 значения. В функции описан курсор, который выводит через запятую нужные (id), и считает общую сумму, которую оплатили эти айдишники.
Проблема в том, что не выходит вывести два столбца. В первой ячейке через запятую id, а вторую ячейку заполнить суммой денег, которую они оплатили. Что нужно сделать, что бы вывести? Если можно подкорректируйте код. Я в SQL только учусь. Спасибо.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`i.s.hopak`@`%` FUNCTION `ABCD`(num VARCHAR ( 5 ), mm INT , mb INT ) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE  res VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE  SU INT;


    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(Receipt_id,""),  SUM(Paid_UAH)
    
    FROM tenantmadeutilitypayment 
  WHERE tenantmadeutilitypayment.PersonalAccount = num AND MONTH(DateOfPay)> mm AND MONTH(DateOfPay)<mb ;
    
    DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = TRUE;
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO res, SU;
    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN(res);
    
    END
```

Comment: Функция по определению возвращает ОДНО СКАЛЯРНОЕ значение. Два она вернуть  не может - устроена так. Если надо вернуть два значения - ну, скажем, сериализуйте их в JSON, а по получении разверните.

Comment: @Akina , я понял, а можно ли как-то выйти из ситуации при помощи курсора?

Comment: А что тут может курсор? Он просто вместо групповой обработки записей выполняет итерационную... но это же всё внутри функции, и никак не влияет на её вывод результата наружу.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем Вы вообще связались с функцией? И зачем курсор, если в его выборке - единственная запись?

Comment: @Akina, мне дали задание написать функцию с курсором, которая возвращает 2 значения... Вот и сижу уже неделю... Сейчас рыскаю по сайтам, нашёл, что как-то это сделать можно, но как...Ещё не понятно.

Comment: Я вижу только вариант типа `SELECT @temp:=function(parameters), LEFT(@temp) AS value1, RIGHT(@temp) AS value2 FROM ...` - если не считать функции в подзапросе и парсинга снаружи... ну ещё вариант второго параметра, который рулит тем, что именно отдаст функция - но в этом случае получится два вызова вместо одного. Впрочем, тут можно извернуться, передавая копию параметров и результат через UDV, и, если это повторный вызов, сразу отдавать результат без запроса в БД.

Comment: @Akina, как много незнакомых слов ))))) Буду пытаться))))

Comment: *нашёл, что как-то это сделать можно* Ссылочку дайте - посмотрим, что имеется в виду.

Comment: @Akina Почти в самом низу сайта https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/plpgsql-cursors

Comment: Это не имеет никакого отношения к MySQL. Забудьте.

Comment: @Akina Извините за наглость. Можно вас попросить переделать мой код? Что бы оно работало))) Уже очень долго сижу с этим заданием. Лекций в принципе нет, а делать нужно(

Comment: ??? Я же вроде однозначно сказал, что ДВА значения вернуть нельзя в принципе. Можно вернуть ОДНО, в котором упакованы два, и снаружи его распаковать. Не более.

Comment: @Akina Я и на это согласен)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример возврата из функции двух значений, сериализованных в JSON:

> ```
> -- тест-таблица
> CREATE TABLE test (id int, val1 INT, val2 INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,11,111), (2,22,222), (3,33,333);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val1 | val2
> -: | ---: | ---:
>  1 |   11 |  111
>  2 |   22 |  222
>  3 |   33 |  333
> ```

> ```
> -- функция
> CREATE FUNCTION return_2_values (in_id INT)
> RETURNS JSON
> DETERMINISTIC
> READS SQL DATA
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE json_var JSON;
>     SELECT JSON_OBJECT('value1', val1, 'value2', val2) 
>         INTO json_var
>         FROM test
>         WHERE test.id = in_id;
>     RETURN json_var;
> END
> ```

> ```
> -- получение объединённого значения в подзапросе и извлечение отдельных значений
> SELECT id, json_output, json_output->"$.value1" value_1, json_output->"$.value2" value_2 
> FROM ( SELECT id, return_2_values(id) json_output
>        FROM test
>        WHERE id IN (1,3) ) subquery;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | json_output                   | value_1 | value_2
> -: | :---------------------------- | :------ | :------
>  1 | {"value1": 11, "value2": 111} | 11      | 111    
>  3 | {"value1": 33, "value2": 333} | 33      | 333
> ```

*[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f646d943efb3c9a9bb3a8e829b9c56b)*

Comment: извините за игнор, отходил. Буду пробовать. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!! На основе вашей функции построил свою!!!! СРАБОТАЛО! Я неделю весь интернет рою!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Akin`е! Он дал  мне ответ!
Вдруг кому будет нужно :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`i.s.hopak`@`%` FUNCTION `return_2_values`(num VARCHAR ( 5 ), mm INT , mb INT ) RETURNS json
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE json_var JSON;
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT('value1', GROUP_CONCAT(Receipt_id,""), 'value2', SUM(Paid_UAH))
         
   
        INTO json_var
        FROM tenantmadeutilitypayment
        WHERE tenantmadeutilitypayment.PersonalAccount = num AND MONTH(DateOfPay)> mm AND MONTH(DateOfPay)<mb ;
    RETURN json_var;
END
```

Ответ :`{"value1": "1,17", "value2": 61.00}`(В моём случае, это правильно!)